# Ruby regex ignores first valid(?) match

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to manipulate SRT subtitle files. An example string `@data` of the start of the file:

```
1
00:01:09,611 --> 00:01:12,404
In co-production with

2
00:01:14,783 --> 00:01:17,034
presents
```

I was matching all the `id`'s with a regex:

```
@data.scan(/^\d+\w*$/)
```

However, this ignored the first `1`, and only output `2..900`. I thought I missed some characters in the regex, and analyzed `@data`:

```
puts @data[0,10].inspect => "1\n00:01:09,611 --> "
```

I don't understand why this first `1` did not match. Also running it with `@data.match()` doesn't yield the `1` but the `2`.

I then added a `\n` before the `1`, and it worked. However, I don't understand why `^` needs a `\n` instead of a real start of the string.

Comment: There seems to be some weird character before the `1` in your string. Try doing `p @data[0, 10].bytes`. The first one wouldn't be 49.

Comment: Got it, the first character in your string seems to be the Byte order mark for UTF-8 - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: `@data.scan(/^\d+\w*$/)` gives me `["1", "2"]` on my environment.

Comment: There should be no BOM in a UTF-8 file; this is usually the result of some mishandling of encodings, often but not always by some buggy Microsoft program that has misunderstood Unicode.

Comment: @tchrist the standard _permits_ it even though it's not needed for UTF-8.

Comment: @dbenhur If a program reading an ***already decoded*** stream of Unicode of code points encounters a BOM, then there is a bug somewhere or other in the processing chain. You should never see that, because a BOM is not data but metadata, and should not occur in a decoded data stream.

Comment: @tchrist Well there seems to be a difference between what the standard requires and what your expectations of a reasonable unicode processing chain is. My read of this [unicode.org FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM) indicates the BOM is allowed, though not recommended, and if it occurs other then at the beginning of a stream, it should be treated as a zero-width non-breaking space for backward compatibility.

Comment: @dbenhur The fundamental flaw with all that is that now you require each and every possible program to specially check for and discard a leading BOM. Anything that must be done without fail each and every time by every agent for correct processing is too important to be left up to the programmer to forget. If you are committed to being leading-BOM–sloppy on UTF-8 files, then your decoder should not return this at all, just as with UTF-16 and UTF-32 processing. Because otherwise you are going to be accumulating more and more of them as you go through iterative processing, and this is messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Dogbert points out in comments, you have a Unicode [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of your string.  I suspect this is an artifact of whatever program is authoring the file you're reading.  You can work around this a couple ways -- remove the character:

```
@data = @data[1..-1] if @data[0] == "\ufeff"
# or
@data.sub!(/\A\ufeff/, '')
```

Or make your scan regexp treat the BOM like a beginning of line anchor with a positive look-behind:

```
@data.scan(/(?:^|(?<=\ufeff))\d+\w*$/)
```

Or, as the Tin Man points out, tell ruby to be BOM-aware when reading the data:

```
@data = File.read('somedata', nil, 0, 'r:BOM|UTF-8')
```

Comment: I assume that is indeed the case. For now I think it was because I used some simple OSX subtitle editor that complained about encoding and saved it as utf. I guess that was the issue. I worked around it by added in the linebreak at the start, but if someone needs to deal with this on a regular basis, you have all the options layed-out in your answer. Accepted.

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is a BOM in the document, Ruby supports checking for a BOM along with using multibyte encodings when reading files. From the "IO Encoding" documentation for [IO.new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-new):

> If “BOM|UTF-8”, “BOM|UTF-16LE” or “BOM|UTF16-BE” are used, ruby checks for a Unicode BOM in the input document to help determine the encoding. For UTF-16 encodings the file open mode must be binary. When present, the BOM is stripped and the external encoding from the BOM is used. When the BOM is missing the given Unicode encoding is used as ext_enc. (The BOM-set encoding option is case insensitive, so “bom|utf-8” is also valid.)

Comment: +1 for teaching us Ruby can be told to do the right thing with the BOM

Comment: BOM have been a thorn in my side many times. I ran into them so seldom that I'd forget they exist, until I'd get garbage in my input data. I had to deal with them when I was writing in Perl, and the first time I encountered UTF-16 encodings was a shock... "WHAT ARE ALL THOSE BINARY ZEROS!!!" :-) It was nice to see that Ruby has something to help.